# Putting a series of integers into a list in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, integer

Is there any way to have an input of a series of random integers e.g. `1 2 3 4` and put them into a list e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
I have tried

```
 a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

and

```
 a = map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: And what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: `input` ->  `raw_input`. Obfuscated questions get obfuscated  answers.

Comment: For both attempts it says `invalid syntax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DeepSpace commented, using [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) solves your problem.

```
a = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

Why? Because input() attempts to evaluate the input from raw_input(), which in this case is invalid (How can you evaluate '1 2 3 4').

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using this method to build your array

```
elements = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    elements.append(i)
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for. It will also end the list at `3` and not `4`.